# Easy way to recover Windows.old folder after Windows 8 PC Refresh?

Tags: windows, windows-8, restore

I recently did a Windows 8 PC refresh, hoping it would solve an issue I'm having, which it didn't. Now I'm hoping there's an easy solution for undoing the refresh.

Is there an easy way to recover any installed programs from the Windows.old folder? I'm hoping to not have to reinstall all the programs, especially seeing as I'd like to keep the settings and configurations for them from before the refresh. Is it possible? Or any suggestions to make it work somehow?

Best I can think of is if it comes to it: Reinstall programs and then copy the old programs over to restore configurations and so on. Still not ideal but I assume it should work?

Comment: App settings you customised may have been saved to the app folder, AppData, registry or who knows where else. Reinstalling would be required, but retrieving all the app settings might not be possible.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971760 This for win 7, but the same steps apply

Comment: You can try your luck with this : http://www.piriform.com/recuva

Comment: @thetechfreak That's an awesome program but not really what the question is about

Comment: Currently it is not possible to recover the already installed apps after doing refresh but the list of apps available before the refresh would be available  in desktop so you can get the list of apps you can install but having the windows.old wont doesn't help the cause.

Answer (score 0):

How to restore Windows 7 after installing the Windows 8 Developer Preview.

This link worked for me , only try this is you want  to  keep your accounts and personal files when installing Windows 8, it has not been verified to work if you performed a “Custom/Clean” install of Windows 8.

You will need the Windows.old folder for this proceedure to work
Text Only Version: http://www.pagestart.com/w8pbrecoverw709291101.html
With screen shots: http://www.pagestart.com/w8pbrecoverw710291101.html

[source](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_install/windowsold-recovery-questions/f58c9d9f-8e7c-465d-bf56-29f7a029716d)